# Unable to generate PMD Reports in multi-format

Tags: maven, jenkins, pmd

I want to generate PMD Reports using maven in .csv and .xml format. I edited my pom.xml as below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <formats>
            <format>csv</format>
            <format>xml</format>
        </formats>
        <rulesets>
            <ruleset>../PMD_RuleSet/PMDRules.xml</ruleset>
        </rulesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Please let me know if I am following the correct configuration.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<formats> not exist :
```

Try:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration> 
            <rulesets>
                <ruleset>../PMD_RuleSet/PMDRules.xml</ruleset>
            </rulesets>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    Execute : mvn clean pmd:pmd -Dformat=csv
    Execute : mvn clean pmd:pmd -Dformat=xml
```

Comment: I want to generate the report both in xml and csv together. Will it be possible ?

Comment: It's not clear what this answer is suggesting readers should do. What does "formats not exist" mean? Is that invalid in this XML format, or is that missing in the OP's XML and in fact is required? Are your "execute" sections part of the XML block in which they appear? Or should that be a separate formatted block?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version> 
     <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>default-pmd</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>pmd</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <format>xml</format>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>format_csv</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>pmd or check or cpd-check</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <format>csv</format>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>  
</plugin>
```

Comment: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'build.plugins.plugin[org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin].executions.execution.id' must be unique but found duplicate execution with id default @ line 250, column 17